# How can I change the overloading indication colour depending on the amount of the overloading?

Tags: colors, microsoft-project

I'd need different colours for different amount of overloading. I am using MS Project 2016.

The current method is that when resource usage is > 100% it's always red no matter how much above it is. Any option to use different colours for different overloading ranges? E.g. Range 1 is red when `100% <` res usage `< 200%`, Range 2 is yellow when `200% <` res usage `< 300%`, Range 3 is green when res usage `> 300%`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a resource number field. Make the formula for the field `[Peak]`
Then set up the graphical indicator like this. You can adjust the indicators and ranges as you see fit.

[image: graphical indicator dialog]